# Populate a table columns with calculations of columns in another table in SQL Server 2008R2 on win 7

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows-7, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to populate a table columns in SQL Server 2008R2 on win 7.

The table 1

```
Id1    Id2   value1    
---------------------
1       a      58218    
1       b       2888       
1       c       916
```

I need  to create a table 2 such that

```
Id1    value1    value1_b_over_a      value1_c_over_a
------------------------------------------------------
1       58218     2888/58218                916/58218
```

I would like to get the table with only one SQL query.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with conditional aggregation:

```
select t1.id1,
       sum(case when id2 = 'a' then value1 end) as value1,
       sum(case when id2 = 'b' then value1 end) / sum(case when id2 = 'a' then value1 end) as value1_b_over_a,
       sum(case when id2 = 'c' then value1 end) / sum(case when id2 = 'a' then value1 end) as value1_c_over_a,
from table1 t1
group by t1.id1;
```

Note:  SQL Server does integer arithmetic.  If you want a number, then cast `value1` to an appropriate numeric type.

```
select t1.id1,
       sum(case when id2 = 'a' then value1 end) as value1,
       sum(case when id2 = 'b' then cast(value1 as float) end) / sum(case when id2 = 'a' then value1 end) as value1_b_over_a,
       sum(case when id2 = 'c' then cast(value1 as float) end) / sum(case when id2 = 'a' then value1 end) as value1_c_over_a,
from table1 t1
group by t1.id1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do a simple pivot and then do your operations.

```
select result.id1,
    result.a value1,
    cast(result.b as decimal) / result.a value1_b_over_a,
    cast(result.c as decimal) / result.a value1_c_over_a
from (
    select *
    from table1 t
    pivot(sum(value1) for id2 in (
                [a],
                [b],
                [c]
                )) as pivotrow
    ) result;
```